# Task queue of size 1 for serial processing

Tags: google-app-engine

I want a serial queue where only one task may process at a time. This is my declaration in queue.xml:

```
<queue>
    <name>pumpkin</name>
    <rate>20/s</rate>
    <bucket-size>1</bucket-size>
    <max-concurrent-requests>1</max-concurrent-requests>
</queue>
```

Does the "rate" parameter have any effect in this setup?

I want tasks to queue up and only process one at a time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queue rate and bucket size do not limit the number of tasks processes simultaneously. See this answer which captured a (now gone) official explanation of these configs better than the [(current) official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/queue#Java_Configuring_the_processing_rate) (you may want to revisit your configs accordingly): https://stackoverflow.com/a/3740846/4495081

However your `max-concurrent-requests` should ensure only one task is executed at a time, according to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/queue#Java_Configuring_the_maximum_number_of_concurrent_requests):

> You can avoid this possibility by setting max_concurrent_requests to a
>   lower value. For example, if you set max_concurrent_requests to 10,
>   our example queue maintains about 20 tasks/second when latency is 0.3
>   seconds. However, when the latency increases over 0.5 seconds, this
>   setting throttles the processing rate to ensure that no more than 10
>   tasks run simultaneously.